# Vue appropriate way to create a stats holder 1 out of 5, 3 out of 5

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an API from the thecatapi

I have a model - breed:

```
{
    ...
    "adaptability": 5,
    "child_friendly": 3,
    ...
}
```

On my page i have a selectedBreed. I would like to create a stats list of some properties of the object, for example - child friendly 3 out of 5

So i have a div, that must contain 3 stars yellow and 2 stars gray.

Currently i don't see any option to make it except:

Create a property, for example: childFriendlyStars - that will be an array of objects like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        class: "yellow"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        class: "yellow"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        class: "yellow"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        class: "gray"
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        class: "gray"
    },
]
```

And do something like:

Something tells me this is not quite correct. **Is there a more appropriate way of doing this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have your star as an SVG (and you will supposedly have `vue-svg-loader` installed in your project) - and then build the stats component like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex">
    <StarIcon v-for="star in maximal" :key="star" 
              width="16" height="16" class="mx-1" 
              :fill="star <= value ? 'green' : 'grey'" 
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import StarIcon from '@/icons/star.svg';

export default
{
  name: 'StatsComponent',
  components:
  {
    StarIcon,
  },
  props:
  {
    value:
    {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    maximal:
    {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

If the current value is 0 - all stars are grey, if the current value is equal to the maximal - all stars are green.